# jbpm 7 +oracle 12+ tomcat processInstanceByteArray is null

Tags: jbpm, tomcat9, xa, narayana

When setting up jbpm7 with oracle 12c tomcat9 and Narayana, getting nullpointer

at:

```
org.jbpm.services.task.impl.command.CommandBasedTaskService.addTask(CommandBasedTaskService.java:302) ~[jbpm-human-task-core-7.38.0.Final.jar:7.38.0.Final].

WARN [Transaction Reaper] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper.check ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffac110002:95f9:5ef5c281:16 in state  RUN

26-Jun-2020 09:47:37.985 WARN [Transaction Reaper] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper.check ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffac110002:95f9:5ef5c281:15 in state  RUN

26-Jun-2020 09:47:37.986 WARN [Transaction Reaper Worker 0] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.checkChildren ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffac110002:95f9:5ef5c281:16 invoked while multiple threads active within it.

26-Jun-2020 09:47:37.991 WARN [Transaction Reaper Worker 0] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.checkChildren ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffffac110002:95f9:5ef5c281:16 completed with multiple threads - thread pool-15-thread-2 was in progress with sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)

sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)

sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
```

Comment: WARN [Transaction Reaper] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper.check ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffac110002:a49b:25 in state  RUN
WARN [Transaction Reaper Worker 0] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.checkChildren ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffac110002:a49b:25 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
 WARN [Transaction Reaper Worker 0] com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.checkChildren ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffffac110002:a49b:25 completed with multiple threads - thread pool-15-thread-1 was in progress with

Comment: hi Mayankneon. Please can you add the whole NullPointer exception stacktrace that you get? The part of the log you provided only says that transaction was finished by a different thread which is just a standard processing in some cases.